# In a Spring test, how to enable the Data Source auto-configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource

I have a Spring Boot application.

I have a JUnit test with a custom Spring context configuration.

How can I enable the JDBC Data Source auto-configuration from the Spring properties like `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.username`, …?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your custom Spring context configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding [`EnableJpaRepositories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) to my test, the data source was initialized.